# Is npm more like mvn or like pip?

Tags: javascript, maven, npm, pip

I'd like to know if Javascript's npm installs dependencies OS-wide like Python's pip (if pip is not using a virtualenv), or if npm installs dependencies more like Java's mvn which stores the things in a local pom.xml file (to me mvn feels more like if it was always in a virtualenv if compared to pip).

So I mainly want to know if it's OS-wide installs or local installs that are performed with npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both!!

- `npm install -g PACKAGE_NAME` will install the package globally.
- `npm install PACKAGE_NAME` will install the package locally in the current folder, under `node_modules/`.
- `npm install --save PACKAGE_NAME` will install the package locally and save it as a dependency in your `package.json`.

Checkout https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/

Answer (score 2):

if you execute just `npm install <dependency name>`  you are telling node to install package only on your current directory this will also create node_modules in current directory you are installing.

and if you execute the `npm install -g <dependency name>` with the `-g` you are saying that you want the node to install the dependency globally and the package will be save on the global node_modules. and most of the global dependencies can be access using CLI

example.

```
$ npm install mocha
```

you can execute the command in the current directory execute the npm install or where the `node_module` is

```
$ $PWD/node_modules/.bin/mocha -v
```

if you

```
$ npm install -g mocha
```

you can execute the command anywhere in your directory on the terminal

```
$ mocha -v
```